# How to get the value of the radio button inside a table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

How to get the value of radio input inside a tr using jquery.

```
var row = $(this).closest('tr');
var status = row.find(input:radio[@name=selectRadioGroup]:checked).val();
```

The above is not helpin

Comment: A selector is a string -> [Selectors | jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run this code in the browser you will get the following error

Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input:radio[@name=selectRadioGroup]:checked

so remove the @ symbol and enclose the expression in quotes like

```
var row = $(this).closest('tr');
var status = row.find("input:radio[name=selectRadioGroup]:checked").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

Selector must be a `string`. Also remove the `@` symbol from the `@name`.

```
 row.find('input:radio[name="selectRadioGroup"]:checked')
```

Demo

```js
console.log($('input:radio[name="selectRadioGroup"]:checked').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="selectRadioGroup" value="1" checked>
<input type="radio" name="selectRadioGroup" value="2" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have an error while using selector. A selector should be a string.

You can achieve what you want to do using following code:

```
<table>
 <tr id="row"> 
 <td> <input type="radio" name="radio_example" value="10" checked>
 </td>
 </tr>
</table>

//jquery

 var status =                                                    
         $('#row input:radio[name="radio_example"]:checked').val();
 console.log(status);  //it will output 10
```